# How to avoid first comma & frame the wished range

Tags: excel, vba, range

after a lot of trying in VBA i could assign the right data to my wished range (D1:E6). Now, i do not know how to avoid the first comma (1. Issue) and why by a sudden the whole sheet is framed instead just the marked range (2. Issue). I thought i command to the system " set the Range rng2 equal to E:E, UP to the range of the before filtered data" - Unfortunately i dont do it at all and acutally its clear for me. I just command set rng2 to E:E till the end but i dont know how to build the bridge in between.

```
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("E:E", ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
```

A:B is not a fixed data frame so it changes by data i download into the Excel, hencewith i can not just command put a frame from D1:E6, it has to be flexible depending on the input data from A:B. But this should not be the problem(?) because of the for Loop.

What i have to do is to combine rng2 with the Loop right?

Is there any approach you could suggest me? Thanks a lot.

[image]

my code

```
    Sub Duplicate()

Dim nA As Long, nD As Long, i As Long, rc As Long
Dim s As String, j As Long

Range("A:A").Copy Range("D1")
    Range("B1").Copy Range("E1")
    Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    rc = Rows.Count
    nA = Cells(rc, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    nD = Cells(rc, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    
       For i = 2 To nD
        v = Cells(i, 4)
        v2 = ""
        For j = 2 To nA
            If v = Cells(j, 1) Then
                v2 = v2 & "," & Cells(j, 2)
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, 5) = Mid(v2, 1)
    Next i

'neu

Dim rng2 As Range:
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("E:E", ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    rng2.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

With rng2.Borders()
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
        
End With

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid first comma, if u don´t mind comma at the end, You can change concatenation to:

```
        If v = Cells(j, 1) Then
            v2 = v2 & Cells(j, 2) & "," 
        End If
```

Or add extra condition for first entry

```
  For i = 2 To nD
    v = Cells(i, 4)
    v2 = ""
    For j = 2 To nA
        If v = Cells(j, 1) Then
        If v2 = "" Then
       v2 = Cells(j, 2)
       Else
           v2 = v2 & "," & Cells(j, 2)
  End If
        End If
    Next j
    With Cells(i, 5)
     .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = Mid(v2, 1)
    End With

Next i
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, i appreciate it. I will test it tomorrow

Comment: i could test it. So, the first approach with changing concatenation is working pretty well. The second appraoch seems to have a problem with the beginning0? It forms f.e the first row to 2.180.233.025.202.540.000.000.000.000.000 do you have any further idea to solve this? Thanks :)!

Comment: Hi , I looked into it, and solved it. I am as much experienced as You , so I solved but don´t why by adding this extra condition  it changes format of cells to be nummber instead of text. My solution is to force format those cells as text by code. I updated my response with adding that extra format condition

Answer (score 0):

Your code needed slight adjustments in few places which I have done. Please refer those changes. It is generally a good programming practice to use cell desired property explicitly i.e. `Cells(i, 4).Value` instead of `Cells(i, 4)` which works because `.Value` is default property.

```
Sub Duplicate()

    Dim nA As Long, nD As Long, i As Long, rc As Long
    Dim s As String, j As Long
    
    Range("A:A").Copy Range("D1")
    Range("B1").Copy Range("E1")
    Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    rc = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
    nA = Cells(rc, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    nD = Cells(rc, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        
    For i = 2 To nD
        v = Cells(i, 4).Value
        v2 = ""
        For j = 2 To nA
            If v = Cells(j, 1) Then
                v2 = v2 & "," & Cells(j, 2).Value
            End If
        Next j
        '\\ Remove first unwanted comma here
        Cells(i, 5).Value = "'" & Mid(v2, 2, Len(v2))
    Next i
    
    '\\ Here we need to bind the range from cell D1 to last row of E in below manner
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D1:E" & nD)
    With rng2
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        With .Borders()
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your support and your advice. Unfortunately it does not result in what im looking for. After the change the numbers would be unreadable because of Cells(i, 5).Value = Mid(v2, 2, Len(v2))..if im changing the middle part(2) to 1 it would give me the old result again. Same with the frame ..in here just D1:E6 has to be framed. But again thanks for your time and support. I added the result of the code in your answer to take a look.

Comment: @Sven That is due to leading 0's in your format which I had not given attention to. I have edited the code at concatenation. I have uploaded example file : https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/r6qu5kdyitmfvt0qgnmbg/SO_67043952.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=en365p8g1adrnfu3sg7ryhc1x